# Database Design for a Hotel Reservation System

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I want to design a database structure for a hotel reservation system.

My schema:

```
client (
  client_id, 
  lastname
)

reservation (
  reservation_id, 
  client_id,
  checkIndate,
  roomno
)
```

My problem is in the check-in part. I have already created a reservation; do I still need to create a check-in table?  If so, what should its schema be?

There are two ways customers can enter a hotel:

1. by reservation (reserving a room prior to arrival) or
2. by checkIn (goes to the hotel without reservation)

**How Do I store the records that are checked-IN in the hotel??**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a couple of thoughts.  I notice that "roomno" is a field in the "reservation" table.  I assume then that you also have a "room" table, which has "roomno" as its primary key and whatever other data that you might keep track of on a room (phone_number, number_of_beds, etc...).

What I would do, is create a table called "Occupancy".  This table would have three fields "client_id", "roomno", and checkin_time.  "client_id" and "roomno" would both be foreign keys (to the client and room tables, respectively).  To ensure uniqueness, I'd concatenate them both to make the primary key (after all, you could have one client buy two rooms).

When the client checks-out, you would remove that row from the "Occupancy" table.  You'll want to archive that row in another table ("history", "pastStays"...something like that) where you'll also want to log the "checkout_time".

In terms of the changes that I have suggested or assumed, here is how they'd look:

```
table: Room
roomno INT
phone_number INT
number_of_beds INT
smoking_allowed BOOLEAN

table: Occupancy
client_id BIGINT (FK referencing Client) (part of PK)
roomno INT (FK referencing Room) (part of PK)
checkin_time DATETIME

table: pastStays
client_id BIGINT (FK referencing Client) (part of PK)
roomno INT (FK referencing Room) (part of PK)
checkin_time DATETIME
checkout_time DATETIME
```

Comment: sir do you have a sample of your database design?? plss....

Comment: sir how could I want to have the occupancy handle many entries for example: occupancy_id 1 will have several client_id and room no in it. How can I do that? Or my single reservation_id (reservation_id 1) will handle multiple occupancy_id.

Comment: sir in my occupancy table, I shouldn't have an occupancy ID?

Comment: @rjtubera that is correct.  There is no need for a surrogate key on the Occupancy table.

Comment: Sir, Could you give me a simpler example regarding multiple room reservation? here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294643/database-design-for-multiple-room-reservation-one-to-many It seems you are very knowledgable regarding databases. I hope you can take a look at it. I've specified my problem there more accurately

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to decouple reservation from check-in. It is also possible that reservations may be done though third party reservations systems (a block of rooms allotted to them). Also single reservation can be for multiple guests, but a checkin is for a single guest. Also you may need separate roomBooking table - one entry per room. It is also typically possible that for single check in guest may use multiple rooms (for different duration). Hence it may be useful to decouple check-in from occupancy. Also you may need to keep inventory (room availability) separately. That means the following tables.

Reservations (id, reserverId, fromDate, toDate) - one entry per reservaion request

RoomBooking (id, resId, roomNo, fromDate, toDate) - one entry per room per reservation

Check-ins (id, resId, guestId, checkInDate, checkOutDate) - one entry per guest

Occupancies (id, checkInId, fromDate, toDate) - one entry per room for specified duration (this is similar to room booking but this is actual, RoomBooking is as planned)

Comment: sir what's the difference between reservations and roombookinG?