# Database Design for Multiple Room Reservation: One To Many

Tags: sql, database-design, normalization, one-to-many, database-normalization

Primary Entities: 
Client
Guest
Reservation
RoomAssignment

I want to implement a multiple room reservation database design. First, I want to explain first the concept:

1. The **Client** is the one who acquires a reservation.
2. The **Client** can only have 1 reservation at a time
3. The **Client** can reserve multiple rooms.
4. The **Guest** is the one who is assigned into a specific room.

   So for the Table:

   `Client (client_id(PK), Name)

        Guest (guest_id(PK), Name)`

   ```
   Reservation (reservation_id(PK), client_id(FK), roomAss_id(FK), checkInDate);
   RoomAssignment (roomAss_id(PK), guest_id(FK), roomno(FK));
   Room(room_id(PK), roomDetails);
   ```

//The problem here is that I don't know how to implement a 1 to many relationship. My Reservation should handle mutliple RoomAssignment? Or my RoomAssignment will handle multiple guest_id and roomno and then I will pass 1 roomass_id into my reservation table?

Thanks I am really confused about this 1 to many relationship. I hope somebody is so kind to help instead of giving me negative points. T_T

Another Attempt:

```
Room(room_id(PK), roomDetails);
Client (client_id(PK), Name)
Guest (guest_id(PK), Name)
Reservation (reservation_id(PK), client_id(FK), checkInDate);
Booking(book_id(PK), reservation_id(FK), room_id(FK));
Lodging(lodge_id(PK), guest_id(FK), book_id(FK))
```

(Client, Room, Guest are already filled), add Reservation, add Booking, add Lodging

Is This Correct??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(**Edit**  Changed my suggestion after thinking about this more.  It's a deeper puzzle than I first thought.)

My preference would be to have the Reservation having a many-to-many relationship (using a bridge table) with rooms.  Call this table, with ReservationID and RoomID foreign keys, something like . . . *Booking*.  Maybe you can think of a better name.  A Booking is a particular room being reserved.  Then, I'd have another bridge table representing the relationship between a Guest and a Booking.  You could maybe call that a *Lodging*. A Lodging is a particular guest being assigned to a particular Booking (a booked room).

This is a neat puzzle you have.  The key is that you have several concrete things that exist on their own and are obviously necessary (reservation, room, guest), but also several other concepts, each with their own attributes, and spring from the relationship between these things.  If this is going to be normalized correctly, you might end up with more tables than you guessed.  Don't think of this as getting more complicated.  Having the **enough of the proper tables is what's going to ultimately simplify this**.  Here are some other suggestions:

- Spend time on the names of each table.  My suggestions above are pretty good, but you can probably improve them.  A booking is both a relationship between other things, but becomes a think itself, with at least one foreign key on another table.
- You should be able to describe what a record on a table represents.  If you can't do that, then your tables suck.  See above how I can describe what a booking and lodging are.  Your design might end up being different, but as you brainstorm different tables, make sure you can describe what a record on that table actually is.
- Consider having Guest and Client being from the same table.  They're both "Contacts" really.  Someone might be a Guest at one point, but a Client the next month.  You might ave an extra data table (one to 0-or-1) for when a Contact is the *Client*.  You're system would only demand basic Contact information if someone is going to just act as a Guest, but more if they're acting as a Client.

Comment: yes, every room should have 1 guest registered on it. so 1 room should have 1 guest too.

Comment: sir another question, where would I get the reservation_id because I'm planning to add the reservations last. My order are as follows: Room(already filled with values/details etc), Client, Guest, RoomAssignment and Reservation. Thanks for answering

Comment: Sir could you please, show it to me. I can't understand clearly. It's better if you show it so that It'll be easier for me. please :)))

Comment: Consider creating a Reservation (with a lot of it's data not filled out) early in the process.  You might not ask for the data until later (cc number, liscense plate, whether they get discount, etc.), but the record should probably be created early.  A *Contact* (Guest, Client, whatever) can certainly be created before a Reservation, but a reservation should come before the other things.  Not that the person using the software would even know a reservation was being created.

Comment: Sir, does that mean that I would add the reservation first before the booking and lodging?

Comment: Sir, I've edited my solution is that correct? Btw, Sir I can't merge the Guest and Client as they have different datas. There details in client that guest doesn't have.

Comment: The tables you added above is correct, in that you've understood my ideas.  My idea is a good example of what might be good for you, but I don't know that it's exactly right for you of course.  You'll probably end up with something slightly different by the time you're finished. /// Keeping Client and Guest separate might be right for you, but consider a **Guest** table with every individual on it, and a **Client** table with extra information for Guests that actually make the reservation.  So, everybody is a Guest at least, but some of them are *also* Clients.  But yeah, you're getting it.